# Getting extra space while using SpanningString

Tags: android, android-custom-view, spannablestring

I am creating a CustomView. I need a string to be a spannable string, to change the colour of a part of the string. The code compiles, but there is a long space between the string and the part that is to be coloured.

Here is the code :

```
String string = mStat1 + "" + mStatValue1;
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(string);
if(mStatValue1<=0) {
     spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(183,108,100)), mStat1.length(), string.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
else {
    spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(117,205,132)), mStat1.length(), string.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
TextPaint textPaint = createTextPaint(mTextColor, mStatSize, Paint.Align.CENTER);
mDynamicLayout = new DynamicLayout(spannableString, textPaint, mWidthPix/2, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 0.0f, 0.0f, false);
```

Here is the image of the view that i get :

[image]

I need to remove the gap between the coloured part of the string and the remaining string. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by remaining string? Is it the path between 1 and 6 for example?

Comment: In the 'Percentage Change', the value is far off as compared to the label.

Comment: The space between the value and 'Percentage Change' is unwanted.

Comment: And it is in the same TextView? Why not to have two separate TextView in a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related with this lines:

```
TextPaint textPaint = createTextPaint(mTextColor, mStatSize, Paint.Align.CENTER);
mDynamicLayout = new DynamicLayout(spannableString, textPaint, mWidthPix/2, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 0.0f, 0.0f, false);
```

You are only changing the color of the text so you can use the method `TextView#setTextColor(int color);` using two separate `TextView` views.

Comment: This is a custom view, so I am not using textviews. I'm drawing these strings on the canvas. Therefore concatinating the string and the value and displaying so that the entire string can be centrally aligned.

Comment: I think you are overkilling your approach by using the draw method. Why not simply extend a, for example LinearLayout, and add the views inside via xml inflation, and finally providing some kind of API from this custom view to set the data? Writting a onDraw method is not so simple and involves so many things. Are you sure it is what you want?

Comment: It needs to be a custom view that can be used later for other modules, hence all the hard work :P

Comment: But what I am proposing to you is also a custom view, but built differently. You can build a custom view as a macro (View + xml) and redistribute it too in a library project.

Comment: Thats what I did now. Had to give up on the idea of drawing everything on the canvas.

Comment: I have done so many views, and it is a hard issue to paint a really complex one without having errors here and there. It is better to not reinvent the wheel and keep using the default views.